# Django MySQL raw query does not return results

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to run a raw query in Django. I am not allowed to use ORM.

I use Django MySQL backend.

If I do basic queries, without parametrizing, the database returns results without problems.

The query I want to run (not returning any results):

```
from django.db import connection
def get_data(variant):
    results = []
    cursor  = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT b.spec_id, b.h_loss, c.gen_type FROM `db-dummy`.spec_gen_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.gen_info a ON a.record_id = c.gen_id JOIN `db-dummy`.spec_data b ON b.record_id = c.spec_id WHERE b.h_loss = 1 AND (a.ref_gen = %s OR a.detail_ref_gen = %s) AND c.gen_type BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ORDER BY a.gen_name;", ('{}%'.format(variant),'{}%'.format(variant),))
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    results = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        results.append(dict(zip(columns, row))) 
    return results
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

I am not getting any error, just results = [] after executing the query and I am sure that that query should return results.

Comment: tryx Like for comparison with strings and wild cards. If that fails, enable shortly general log and see what query you get and test it

Comment: You mean using LIKE %s instead of something = %s ?

Comment: yes , give it a try

Comment: That was it, if you add an answer I'll mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE` instead of = when comparing Strings with wild cards

```
cursor.execute("SELECT b.spec_id, b.h_loss, c.gen_type FROM `db-dummy`.spec_gen_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.gen_info a ON a.record_id = c.gen_id JOIN `db-dummy`.spec_data b ON b.record_id = c.spec_id WHERE b.h_loss = 1 AND (a.ref_gen LIKE %s OR a.detail_ref_gen LIKE %s) AND c.gen_type BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ORDER BY a.gen_name;", ('{}%'.format(variant),'{}%'.format(variant),))
```